# Better Mod Rewrite - non www. => www. is setting my $1 and tripping up my switch case for page names

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to allow spaces, etc, in my mod rewrite to accomodate all scripts. I am also forcing www.

When i go to http://mydomain.com 
it goes to 
http://www.mydomain.com

But my PHP script thinks parameter 1 is set to www. or http://, and my router is set to switch parameter 1

```
switch ($rewrite1){
case "": static::home; break;
case "foo": static::foo; break;
default: static::pageNotFound; break;
}
```

When i do in htacces it works

```
#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ index.php?sn=$1 [QSA]
```

But i was told i needed

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?sn=$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

My full mod rewrite is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?sn=$1 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ index.php?sn=$1 [QSA]
Options -Indexes
```

How can I prevent that while accomodating more options in URL? or is it impossible? Also is %{REQUEST_FILENAME} the best way to make files avoid our router, or is there another way to keep known directories and file types from touching our router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need `L` flag in your first rule. Keep your code like this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?sn=$1 [QSA,L]
```